# Ubuntu Installer can't find any HDDs

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, dell

I recently bought a Dell Poweredge r610, and I created a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu Server. It was bought used, and I do not know if someone had already installed some other OS on it.

When I started setting it up, it worked fine. After I selected **Use the Entire Disk**, it showed the screen to pick a disk. None showed up. The drive is a 500GB SATA Seagate Barracuda installed in Slot 1. A little light on the side is green, although I may not have installed it right.

I don't know what other posts mean by using things like the Terminal, since there's no option for that.

Comment: These might be helpful: [InstallingANewHardDrive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) --> note: Drives that are going to be used only under Ubuntu should be formatted using the ext3/ext4 file system..;  and [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and [Ubuntu Community Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).

Comment: To use terminal, type "terminal" in the ubuntu search icon and select. Then you can follow commands in the links above.

Comment: @BrendanDarrer I'm installing Ubuntu Server, there's no search bar in the installation screen as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you get it from the USB ubuntu drive, when you first start the install?

Comment: If you have installed ubuntu already, then try and boot it from the USB installation stick, and enter ubuntu from there. Then you can use `terminal` to issue commands. See: [How do I boot from USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347233/how-do-i-boot-from-usb). Remember to go into BIOS to select USB in the boot option first.

Comment: @BrendanDarrer This is during installation

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to narrow down the possibilities. When booting, I pressed Ctrl + R to view RAID settings. It turns out the drive had been connected properly, but the system didn't yet know it existed through the PERC 6/i controller.